# Google Sheets Financial API - dates are wrong

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I'm using Google Sheets for tracking my mutual funds portfolio, and I'm supposed to call the function below to get the timestamp of the most recent change of the VASIX fund share price:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("VASIX", "date")
```

The problem is that the date, returned by this function, is typically two-three days late.

What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOOGLEFINANCE("VASIX", "date") returns The date at which the net asset value was reported. For mutual funds this is at market close on trading days. So, for example, Sat. would show the market close on Fri. The date won't change again until Tue. when Mondays NAV is reoported. Try =GOOGLEFINANCE("VASIX", "close","8/25/2017") requesting specific dates over a weekend through Tuesday to see what is happening.

Comment: Right now (Thursday, 8/31/2017, 11:15am) this function returns "8/29/2017 20:00:00", which is NOT yesterday

Comment: And the close price hasn't changed since 8/29/2017/

Comment: That's true for the "VASIX"...But - many other funds with changed close price are shown with the date "8/29/2017 20:00:00". Example - "VFIAX"